# The EC2 user_data script dos not run

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, ec2-userdata

Hi i'm stuck with my user_data script because the script is no executed by the ec2 and i don't really understand why

On terraform i have

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_b" {
    ami = "ami-0c2b8ca1dad447f8a"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.private_b.id
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]

    tags = {
      Name = "my-ec2-b"
    }

    key_name = "vockey"
    user_data = file("./user_data.sh")
}
```

with the following script

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo "test" > /home/ec2-user/test.txt
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install httpd -y
sudo systemctl start httpd
sudo systemctl enable httpd
sudo echo "Hello, World" | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html
```

On aws console i can see that the script is there
[image]

However if i try to go on my ec2 with ssh i can see that the script has not been executed

[image]

Comment: There are two log files you can look at: `/var/log/cloud-init.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`.

Comment: thank you thanks to you i've seen that it was an issue with my ami id